# ruby gem install to 1.9.1 instead of 1.8

Tags: ruby, gem

I ran the following lines in linux

```
gem install mysql
```

And it installed the mysql gem to `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems`. That's not where I want it.  I wnat it at `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems`.  I could just copy the files over to the 1.9.1 gems directory.  But is there an option in the `gem install mysql` command that lets me install the gem to 1.9.1 instead of 1.8?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? Are both versions of Ruby properly installed?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04.  Both versions of ruby are working fine, except 1.9.1 is missing the mysql gem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the default version of Ruby on Ubuntu 14.04 would be 1.9.1. I don’t know what’s wrong with your system in that regard.

If you want to target a specific Ruby version, simply use the fully qualified name:

```
gem1.9.1 install mysql
```

Likewise, you can use `ruby1.9.1` to explicitly request the Ruby 1.9.1 interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

FROM gem help examples:

- Install 'rake', but only version 0.3.1, even if dependencies
  are not met, and into a user-specific directory:

  gem install rake --version 0.3.1 --force --user-install  {/var/lib/gems/... in your case)

Comment: That’s not a proper way to solve this problem. If native extensions are required, they have to be compiled against the correct Ruby version.